# Use variable once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that refetches events in calendar every 10sec. But before that it needs to be rendered correctly (different colors if past time or future time) so I use variables `now` and `time` to get time. But now I am getting `time` that is set first which is always same and I need to get `time` which is set with setInterval function.
Can I somehow use first variable `time` just once or is there some other soltion?

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
},  10 * 1000);

if (eventTime < time) {
    //do something
}else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: `var time = now.getTime()` in your `setInterval` is creating a separate variable called `time` that is limited to inside the `setInterval` function. Just remove the `var` part and it will refer to the original `time` variable instead.

Comment: Where are you fetching `eventTime` from? What is that second code paragraph supposed to do, and why is it in that scope?

Comment: Why do you render only once (before fetching the calender events)?

Comment: This interval looks like it could create a cascade error (at the moment it's unlikely considering how long the time difference is but) you may want to consider switching to a `setTimeout` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `var` from `now` & `time` in function in setInterval, It recreating those vars there.

And for accessing new value call every thing after changing the `time`.

try like bellow

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
setInterval(function(){
    now = new Date();
    time = now.getTime();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

    if (eventTime < time) {
       //do something
     }else {
       // do something else
     }
 },  10 * 1000);
```

Comment: No. Only the `var` statments elsewhere, but don't entirely omit them.

Comment: sorry @Bergi I didn't get you.

Comment: I'm saying that removing `var` is not the solution, because that would create a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `var` keyword inside the function, `time` and `now` are created again within the function's scope. That means they're different from the variables outside the function although they have the same name. If you remove that keyword, the value of the variables in global scope will be updated and you can access the values set by your function from outside.

Also, I would put that if-statement inside of the intervalled function. JavaScript will execute your if-statement before setting that time variable to the new value otherwise.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/7VBcn/1/